# How can I make rm -rf ask for confirmation just once at the directory level?

Tags: bash, directory, rm, interactive

If I use `rm -rfi`, this asks me every time each file is deleted. If I have a list of `rm -rf` commands, how can I make it so that the machine asks me for confirmation just once (when trying to delete the directory itself)

Answer (score 10):

With some `rm` implementations (DragonFly BSD where it comes from, FreeBSD and GNU at least), the  `-I` (capital i) is what you are looking for.
`-i` asks for confirmation for every file, while the `-I` (capital i) ask for confirmation once when files are more than 3 or you are deleting recursively.

Answer (score 1):

```
zsh -c 'rm -f -- **/*(^/)'
rm -ri -- *
```

This will recursively (`**/`) remove everything (`*`) that isn't a directory (`^/`) with `zsh`; then use your existing shell to interactively remove what's left (directories). To include dotfiles in the initial removal, use:

```
zsh -c 'rm -f -- **/*(D^/)'
```

followed by:

```
rm -ri -- *
```

Answer (score 1):

The snippet below will ask for confirmation once, then it will delete the entire directory `'path/to/delete'`

1. Use `read -p 'question ' answer` to display the `'question '` to the user and store the answer in the variable `${answer}`. (The trailing space in `'question '` makes the prompt more readable)
2. Use the test clause `[ ]` with the string equality `=` operator to ensure the variable `${answer}` contains the `'expected answer'`
3. Use the and operator `&&` to stop if any of the steps does not succeed - e.g. `[Ctrl]+[C]` was used to interrupt the `read` or the test clause `[ ]` wasn't true
4. Before ever writing `rm -rf` - Think of scenarios where things can go horribly wrong. Brainstorm ways to mitigate the risk as much as possible
5. When all of the conditions above are met, remove the directory forcibly with `rm -rf`

```
PATH_TO_DELETE='path/to/delete'
read -p "Delete path '${PATH_TO_DELETE}'? [y/N] " YN && [ "${YN}" = 'y' ] && rm -rf "${PATH_TO_DELETE}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Well this could be a wild solution, but wanted to share anyway!

```
function rm_ {
   [[ -d "$1" ]] && rm -rI "$1" || rm -f "$1"
}
```

Then use `rm_ <directory|file>`. If its `directory` you get `rm: remove all arguments recursively?` , else nothing and the file would be deleted.

This way , there will be  no prompt to user while deleting files, as well as the user gets a prompt  while deleting a directory.

If only `rm -rI` were to be used , user gets confirmation prompt for both files and directories and so I used a combination of both `rm -f` and `rm -rI`.